# Allow or prohibit permutation in tensorflow loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm training a network to reconstruct coordinates of specific structures in an image. Until now, my loss function contains three 2D vectors (i.e. 6 variables) for the coordinates which are learned via `MSE`, and three corresponding classifiers learned via `SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy`, indicating if there are 0, 1, 2 or 3 of these structures present. I thought it might be beneficial to give tensorflow the information that it is neglectable in which order that the vectors are reconstructed as long as the classifier is still correct. Simple example:

```py
loss(tf.constant([[30, 20, 15, 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=tf.float32),
     tf.constant([[0, 0, 15, 7, 30, 20, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)) == 0
```

To implement this I used [`tf.argsort`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort) on the magnitude of each vector:

```py
def sort(tensor):
    x = tf.unstack(tensor, axis=-1)
    squ = []
    for i in range(len(x) // 2):
        i *= 2
        squ.append(x[i] ** 2 + x[i+1] ** 2)
    new = tf.stack(squ, axis=-1)
    return tf.argsort(new, axis=-1, direction='ASCENDING',
                      stable=False, name=None)
```

and consecutively permuted the tensor:

```py
def permute_tensor_structure(tensor, indices):
    c = indices + 6
    x = indices * 2
    y = indices * 2 + 1
    v = tf.transpose([x, y])
    v = tf.reshape(v, [indices.shape[0], -1])
    perm = tf.concat([v, c], axis=-1)
    return tf.gather(tensor, perm, batch_dims=1, name=None, axis=-1)
```

I did the same for my ground truth and got the network up and running.

Minimal example extracted from my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_addons.losses import SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy


def compute_permute_loss(truth, predict):
    l2 = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    ce = SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy()
    indices = sort(predict[:, 0:6])
    indices2 = sort(truth[:, 0:6])
    predict = permute_tensor_structure(predict, indices)
    truth = permute_tensor_structure(truth, indices2)
    L2 = l2(predict[:, 0:6], truth[:, 0:6])
    BCE = tf.reduce_sum(ce(truth[:, 6:], predict[:, 6:],))
    return 3 * L2 + BCE


class Test(tf.test.TestCase):
    def test_permutation_loss(self):
        tensor1 = tf.constant(
            [[30, 20, 15, 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],
            dtype=tf.float32)
        tensor2 = permute_tensor_structure(tensor1, tf.constant([[2, 1, 0]]))
        loss = compute_permute_loss(tensor1, tensor2)
        self.assertEqual(loss, 0,
                         msg="loss for only permuted tensors is not zero")
        tensor3 = tf.constant(
            [[29, 22, 15, 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],
            dtype=tf.float32)
        loss = compute_permute_loss(tensor3, tensor2)
        self.assertAllClose(loss, (1.0 + 4.0) / 2.0,
                            msg="loss for values is not rmse")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.test.main()

# [ RUN      ] Test.test_permutation_loss
# [       OK ] Test.test_permutation_loss
```

However, I'm afraid the permutation in the loss could backfire and impair tensorflows backpropagation. Maybe somebody already faced a similar problem? Or has deeper knowledge on tensorflows graph building and back propagation? I would be grateful for every suggestion or input.

Comment: It is unclear what your specific issue is.

Comment: I would like to know if my approach is legit. Tensorflow throws no errors. However it seems like the network is learning slower than with no sorting. I.e. setting the first coordinate on the first vector etc... I would expect to increase the networks capabilities with introducing this additional degree of freedom. Thinking certain neurons can focus on certain regions of the image (since the order doesn't matter). But this doesn't seem to be the case. So maybe sorting in the loss function has some kind of impairment in the back propagation I didn't think about?